# response 404 (backend NotFound), service rules for the path non-existent for GKE ingress for microfront-end deployment and service

Tags: gke-networking

I have created the Deployment and service for the microfront end app. Also created the GKE ingress. There are 2 services for 2 Deployments. In the GKE ingress yaml I have mentioned the 2 backend services.
I am getting 404 if I do the curl to the ingress external IP

Comment: share the yaml file config for ref. without that no one will be able to help much. if question closed feel free to create new one with more proper details.

Comment: i think you can edit the question add the yaml file and format it properly, so someone could help instead sharing it in comment without formatting.